# Multicast route not linking to userspace

Tags: linux-kernel, network-interface, multicast

Ok So I have a user space application that needs to get data from multicast traffic, however I cannot seem to get the traffic out of kernel space and into userspace where the application can utilize the data. I am wondering for redhat am I missing a kernel module possible? as I will show below it looks like I have everything setup up for making a route to userland but when I create the route it doesn't actually create any kind of link like I would expect.

What I have verified so far:

```
sysctl file
# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth2.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0

net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

kernel.sysrq = 0

kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

kernel.msgmnb = 65536

kernel.msgmax = 65536

kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

kernel.shmall = 4294967296

net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 0 #allow multicast through the kernel
```

so my kernel should not be filtering the traffic if I am correct. also the fire wall is turned off however I did modify the iptable rules to allow any multicast traffic through on the INPUT chain I have created a route-eth2 file to create my route

```
#create the persistent multicast route

224.0.0.0/4 via 0.0.0.0  dev eth2
```

I also put the gateway to 0.0.0.0 since there is no router between the target and the source of the multicast traffic. this is where my multicast inexperience shines, I have software that attaches a socket on eth2 to a port and requests access to the multicast group on 224.0.0.70 (fyi this software has worked before using multicast on a different linux  machine same os and all) I expected to see some sort of link to my multicast address 224.0.0.70 from my subnet 224.0.0.0/8 route I created but this is at least right now not the case. this is what ip route show has prior to opening the program

```
10.50.100.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.50.100.3
192.168.11.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.11.3
//more stuff 
224.0.0.0/8 dev eth2
default via 149.97.48.3 dev eth0  proto static
```

after opening the program I looked at ip maddr and can see 224.0.0.70 show up on eth2 which makes me think that it has requested and joined the group I believe, however even after seeing this in maddr and using tcpdump to check and verify I am getting the multicast traffic to that interface I see nothing on the user side of things, nor do I see any change to ip route show like I expected. ip route show after opening the program

```
224.0.0.0/8 dev eth2
```

also of interest I do not have mroute or pimd or smcroute, what I have seen used quite a bit but apparently red hat especially red hat 6 does not support those so igmp I "think" is what I am to use but I dont see how I can use it other than enable it which I have done and verified using ifconfig.

So I am left thinking my route create is flawed or maybe I do not have a kernel module installed that I need in order to finish connecting the route to the program maybe? any thoughts and clarification would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: The application code must be multicast-aware. An application not intended for multicast will not receive multicast by just telling it, here use 224.5.6.7. it must do extra steps (like setsockopt(fd, ... , IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, ...).  If you're not sure the app is correctly configured, test receiving your multicast flow with socat: http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html

Comment: correct and yes it does have these and to the best of my knowledge it is working as when I launch the program I see the 224.0.0.70 address become assigned to eth2 as the program requested to join that multicast group but I have not used the socat tool and I will look into that know thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really a network expert, but in my experience, getting multicast traffic up and running takes little more than the following line:

```
sudo route add -net XXX.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 IFACE
```

Where XXX is the subnet and IFACE is the interface.  Here is what my `ip route show` looks like before and after.

Before:

```
default via 10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto dhcp metric 109 
default via 192.168.14.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 110 
10.0.3.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.15 metric 109 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s8 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.14.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.14.146 metric 110 
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s9 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.102 metric 107
```

After:

```
default via 10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto dhcp metric 109 
default via 192.168.14.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 110 
10.0.3.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.15 metric 109 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s8 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.14.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.14.146 metric 110 
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s9 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.102 metric 107 
224.0.0.0/8 dev enp0s3 scope link
```

I, too, do not have the pimd, smcroute, or mroute modules installed.  If you expect there to be traffic on that port, you can test access to userspace through tools like `socat`.

I'm going a little more substance to this... if you do not properly configure the route prior to attempting to join the group and configure multicast from within your program, you should be greeted with an error while attempting to gain membership to a group (`setsockopt( sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq))`).

If you're able to join the group, then this requirement has been satisfied.

Do you have any of the code that you've written specifically for configuring the multicast port within your software?

Comment: yes but that code was part of a proprietary program that was handed down to me, I have since written a bare bones version that subscribes to the group and started receiving the messages so the error is somewhere in that software. but thank you for answering and it did help answer some unknowns to be about how it should look, I am not normally working on networking. the socat tool was also very quick and useful and I also started receiving messages through it which led me to write a program.

Comment: I figured that it was proprietary (as you would most likely have provided it immediately otherwise).